# Ubuntu Server for armhf architecture

Tags: server, 20.04, arm, architecture, arm64

I download [Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) 20.04 for arm64 architecture. and it was fine.
now I want to know, Where can I get it for armhf architecture (if there is such an image)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server images available [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.2/release/) (including armhf).